# How can I use a git bash terminal profile in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-2019, git-bash

Visual Studio 2019 has recently added a new (much-needed) terminal feature in its 16.6 version.
It's really great, but I'm having a hard time integrating git bash in the profiles.

I've tried a few variations of arguments and whatnot of the following profile:

[image: Bash Profile]

But whenever I try selecting that profile, the terminal shortly displays a blank screen, then opens the default PowerShell terminal.

What am I doing wrong and how can I configure the profile correctly?

Comment: This works in Visual Studio 16.8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution I am using while waiting for a better one:

Shell Location: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
Arguments: /k ""%VSAPPIDDIR%..\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" & bash"

Essentially, I am launching cmd and running the "bash" command at launch, effectively nesting the bash terminal within cmd.

Comment: This worked for me. It launches Git Bash within the embedded terminal. Noice!

Comment: `bash` isn't in my PATH though, so whenever this starts-up I get the error `'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Either add bash to your path or use the full path to `bash.exe` rather than only `bash` (i.e. `(...)VSAPPIDDIR%..\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" & "C:\Program Files\GitOrSomething\bash.exe""`

Answer (score 8):

In case you haven't figured it out already: You need to add argument -i (to make the shell interactive), and I also recommend --login (to make the shell read default profile configuration files).

Try adding the following in the Arguments field:

--login -i

Comment: This solution did not change the result for me. Trying to open the profile skips back directly to the Powershell profile.

Comment: I added --login -i -l and it works

Answer (score 6):

I used C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe as the Shell Location, and it worked fine.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**My Workaround**:

What you no one mentioned in all of these replies is that you need the shell not the executable different things...

**Shell Location:** C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe

**Arguments:** (If you have any preferences add here, it works without)

And...

Walah!

[image: How it looks in the VS2019 Terminal]

Comment: Don't forget to add --login -i -l as a argument